# SQL query to fetch persons with more than one postcode address via join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres 13 and have the following tables (tables column are truncated for clarity) essentially a join table (location) between person and address with extra columns and it's own primary key (this I cannot change).

`Person` table

```
 person_id
-----------
         1
         2
```

`Location` table

```
 location_id | status | address_id | person_id
-------------+--------+------------+-----------
           1 |      1 |          1 |         1
           2 |      1 |          2 |         1
           3 |      1 |          3 |         2
           4 |      1 |          4 |         2
```

`Address` table

```
 address_id | postcode
------------+----------
          1 |       NR1
          2 |       NR2
          3 |       NR3
          4 |       NR3
```

What I would like to achieve is a query that will fetch all person ids that have addresses with more than one postcode and a location status of 1. The person table has over 10 million records and each person can have multiple addresses so I would like to use limit and offset so I can get the data via multiple queries.

The result of the sample data in the tables would just return person_id 1 as it has two different postcodes (NR1 & NR2), whereas person_id 2 has two identical postocdes (NR3 & NR3)

My first attempt without paging is this which seems to be working, but I am sure there are better ways of doing it

```
SELECT sq.person_id
FROM
(
    SELECT
        p.person_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT a.postcode) AS count_postcode
    FROM person p 
        INNER JOIN location l
             ON p.person_id = l.person_id
        INNER JOIN address a
            ON a.address_id = l.address_id
    WHERE l.status = 1
    GROUP BY p.person_id
) sq
WHERE sq.count_postcode > 1;
```

Comment: And what about your expected results for the sample data?

Comment: I have editted the post to include extra paragraph with expected outcome of data listed in tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your tables and do a distinct count on the Postcode column, grouped per person:

```
select l.person_id
from location l
join address a on a.address_id = l.address_Id
group by l.person_id
having Count(distinct a.postcode) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Stu, much cleaner than using a subquery